# Cron Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: bash, cron

I'm using a cloud and I synchronize every data in a folder on my cloud.
I want to backup those data in another folder on my computer. This is the reason why I want to use a cron.

In my bashrc, I've added a command to backup my computer data folder in a backup data folder. It works.

If I add this command in a crontab, it doesn't work.

Here my crontab line : `*/10 * * * * mycommand` 
I've already tried to restart crontab and doesn't work.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: does `crontab -e` list your cron?

Comment: Yes it list my crontab with my command. 
Maybe cron doesn't tale aliases ?

thanks for answering

Comment: Aliases? Is `mycommand` a shell alias?

Comment: Yes my command is a shell alias

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the cron environment is a little limited.

I found [This topic on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/119273/how-to-use-my-aliases-in-my-crontab) which explain how to enable aliases manually. Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

and see if there are any error messages.

Also, it is advisable to pass the full path of the command like below:

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/echo "Hello"
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for caring intention on my post.

After using `code`grep CRON /var/log/syslog `code` here are my results : 
(myuser) CMD (mycommandalias)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Same error for /bin/echo "Hello"

Thanks

Comment: Seems to install postfix.
Just feel stupid to not check the log...

Comment: @Thibaud, You can install a mail service, postfix for example, to solve this problem by using sudo apt-get install postfix command in Ubuntu. Also try my command once and let me know if this helps.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, i just installed postfix. Now i don't have error in my syslog.
Oct  2 09:19:01 myuser CRON[26102]: (myuser) CMD (mycommand)

But the command doesn't work. It's working in my terminal but not in the cron.

Thanks for caring intention

Comment: @Thibaud, could you please let me know if you checked my command.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, the problem is the same for your command, I don't see any "Hello" on my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to run your job each 10 mins then you could give a try to following entry.

```
00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /with/full/path/of/your_scipt
```

This script should run each 10 mins daily. you could use `crontab -e` for editing it and could use `crontab -l` to list cron entries.

Comment: I don't use a script but an alias of my command
The alias works in a terminal.

Thanks for your intention

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : 
It works if i don't use shell alias for my command.

If someone know why alias don't work in cron, i take the information.

Thank you evryone for helping.